# Setting Currency in Conditonal Formatting

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my Excel for a cell I check the condition and wants to apply the currency format,

1. USD  (For Example : USD 44.345)
2. EUR  (For Example : EUR 11.000)

I tried to apply like below:

```
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = "##0.0###"
```

I'm able to add text after the value like below:

```
MyRange.FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = "##0.0###"" My text"""
```

But I need to add currency text before the price.

Please help me to acheive the above currency format.

Comment: How to prepend the text USD or EUR in the value ?

Comment: I want to add the text before value.. Not after ?

Comment: `"USD" ##0.0###`?

Comment: I tried adding all possibilitied (before, inside), its giving error only

Comment: Well you need to double up the quotes.

Comment: Don't you want to use `"[$EUR] #,##0.00"` and `"[$USD] #,##0.00"`?

Comment: If system setting for Decimal value is ,(Comma) insteadof .(Dot)... The number format i defined here is showing error ("[$EUR] #,##0.00") because it .(Dot)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by escaping individual characters. That also means that you could set it dynamically i guess

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b2").NumberFormat = "\U\S\D #,##0.00"
```

for example: I experimented a bit - see no logic in this, but

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b2").NumberFormat = "\EUR #,##0.00"
```

works and

```
ActiveSheet.Range("a1:b2").NumberFormat = "\USD #,##0.00"
```

throws an error